# Can I use expanding foam to seal a hole behind my kitchen gas stove?

Tags: drywall, kitchens, pest-control, stove, pest

There is a hole in the wall behind my kitchen gas stove where some pipes for the stove come through. But mice also come through there. I want to seal the gap using expanding foam, but when I read the can, they all say "flammable, keep away from electric wires, gas, heat, etc).

How can I seal this gap? Is there non-flammable foam, or should I use copper mesh?

Comment: With mice, would not use anything except metal, but they will probably just make a hole somewhere else.  Get rid of mice, then fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you probably can use expanding foam there.

Read the label more closely. It may mention that the product contains a *flammable gas* as its propellant. It could be ignited by sparks, open flame, or even hot surfaces. The propellant dissipates within moments of being discharged from the can and the flammability hazard quickly fades.

The label may also mention that the cured foam is *combustible*. The difference is that a *flammable* substance ignites and burns easily at ambient temperatures, while a *combustible* substance requires some elevated temperature to get it started burning. Like cured foam, the plastic insulation on your electrical wires, the paper on your drywall, the wood structure, the kitchen cabinets, and other nearby materials are combustible. Foam used *inside* the oven would likely combust, but with any normal oven, foam used on a wall nearby would be safe.

That said -- crip659 is correct: foam is not likely to be effective against your mouse problem.

Comment: There's also expanding foam available that's a fire block.

Comment: It might be more hype than reality, but they also make foam that claims to block pests: https://www.greatstuff.dupont.com/products/greatstuff-pestblock.html

Comment: @GregHill Thanks for the answer. Is there any specific brand of foam you recommend? Loctite? Or is the above mentioned "fire block" type of foam better for my case?

Comment: @Kingamere Product recommendations are off-topic, in part because brand availability varies across geography and over time. Whatever brand is stocked at your preferred store will be as good as anything else. Often there is "normal" and "door & window" product. The door & window stuff is softer and expands with less force. Those characteristics aren't necessary here but won't hurt either. Likewise fire-stop type foam is not required here, but there's no harm in using it (it'll cost a little more and may be more difficult to find though).